# 1 -form on Compact Manifold

Tags: smooth-manifolds, differential-forms

This question was asked in my quiz on smooth manifolds and I couldn't solve it during the exam. I tried this problem again but still couldn't solve it. I am not really good in solving problems related to differential forms despite reading course notes 3 times. So, I am posting it here looking for hints. I have been following introduction to smooth manifolds by John Lee along with my course notes.

> Question:(a) Let $ M$ be a compact manifold of dimension $n>1$. Show that a nowhere vanishing $1$-form on $M$ cannot be exact.

(b) Let $w=fdx + gdy$ be a closed $1$-form on $\mathbb{R}^2$. Show that $w$ is exact.

Attempt: (a) Let on the contrary the $1$-form be exact.  That means if a was $1$-form then it is exterior derivative of another $1$-form $b$. But unfortunately, I am not sure which result to use to proceed towards a contradiction. Can you please give some hints?

(b) form $w$ is closed implies that $dw =0$, which implies that $dw= df dx + dg dy+ f d^2x + g d^2 y$. I have to show that $w$ is exact. But again I am not sure how should I proceed.

Kindly give a couple of hints. I shall be really thankful.

Comment: If a one-form $\omega$ is exact, then it is $db$ for some *zero*-form (aka smooth function) $b$. Now why must $db$ vanish somewhere? By the way, you shouldn’t just read the class notes. You don’t learn anything by doing that. Fight them! Study every nook and cranny of every proof, every place where every hypothesis is used, work through the examples again… merely reading is far too passive to let you understand the topic.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No where vanishing exact $1$-form on compact manifold.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2998285/no-where-vanishing-exact-1-form-on-compact-manifold)

Comment: @Aphelli You are right.

Comment: @ArcticChar No, it's about boundry.

Comment: @Aphelli Can you please elaborate on your comment to give a proof of both (a) and (b)?

Comment: Do you mean that your manifold has boundary? If that's the case, (a) is false.

Comment: @ArcticChar Can you please elaborate on the question and write an answer?

Comment: @Avenger yes, that one answer your question. Look at the Jason DeVito answer

Comment: @FedericoFallucca Ok man. I will have a look at it soon. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

For (a), if $w = db$ for $b$ a zero-form (smooth function $M \to \mathbb{R}$), then by compactness this smooth function achieves a global maximum at some $p \in M$. Choosing a local coordinate system $x^1, \ldots, x^n$ around $p$, the differential $d$ is given by
$$
   db = \sum_i \frac{\partial b}{\partial x^i} dx^i,
$$
which is zero at the maximum since $b$ is smooth.

For (b), there are several ways to prove this. Since we are only working in $\mathbb{R}^2$, the most down-to-earth would be something like the following: the condition that $\omega = f dx + g dy$ is closed implies that $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial g}{\partial x}.$$ (Why?) This is a good sign: we are after all looking for some function $F$ with the property that its $x$-partial derivative is $f$ and its $y$-partial derivative is $g$, and then this equality is just saying
$$\frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial x \partial y} = \frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial y \partial x},$$
which is true. To reverse-engineer what $F$ should be, we start at one point and then integrate along paths to get the result at any other point. Start by defining $F(0) = 0$ (this is arbitrary, because shifting $F$ up or down by a constant won't affect any of these partial derivatives). Then for any other point $p = (x_0, y_0)$, define
$$
   F(x_0, y_0) = \int_{0}^{x_0} f(x, 0) dx + \int_{0}^{y_0} g(x_0, y) dy.
$$
Is it clear what these integrals are doing? They are traversing from $(0,0)$ to $(x_0, y_0)$ by going first horizontally along the $x$-axis, then vertically up to $(x_0, y_0)$. As they progress, they are measuring how much $F$ is supposed to be increasing, via its partial derivatives in the appropriate direction. One can then do some analysis of partial derivatives and use the FTOC to show that the function $F$ we have defined this way is smooth, and that $dF = f dx + g dy$.

This can all be done much more generally. The path we took to get to $(x_0, y_0)$ was arbitrary; one could use a straight line, or another curve instead. For a lot of this worked out carefully on manifolds, see Lee's *Smooth Manifolds*, Chapter 8, I think.

I'd be remiss if I didn't mention for posterity that this is all subsumed by the theorem that de Rham cohomology is homotopy-invariant. De Rham cohomology is an algebraic gadget measuring how far apart the properties of being closed and exact are. Homotopy invariance means that we can squish the whole plane down to a point, check that every closed 1-form is exact on a point (which is trivial because there aren't any since a point is zero-dimensional), and conclude that the same is true for $\mathbb{R}^n$ for any $n$. Very powerful! See for example Lee, Chapter 17.

Comment: In your paragraph beginning with "For (b)", I think you want "the condition that $\omega = fdx + gdy$ is **closed**..."

Comment: @C.D. Thank you very much for helping me.

Comment: @C.D. Can you please help me with this also? I am badly struck on this and I don't have any offline help